# Merge single column of one table into another based on ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't want a temporary join, I want to actually update one column to be the equivalent of its counterpart from another table based on sharing an ID. It would be something like this:

```
UPDATE parts2.PartNumber 
SET parts2.PartNumber=parts.PartNumber 
WHERE parts2.id=parts.id;
```

Thanks in advance, sorry if this is a repeat question but I can't seem to find the answer much to my surprise.  The above code is giving a syntax error of `unknown column parts2.id in WHERE clause` even though that column certainly exists.

Comment: Why you don't want a temporary join?

Comment: I'm parsing a giant list of snowmobile parts into a database for a client and somewhere along the way managed to set the Part Number for every single row to be the same, overwriting the originals.  I've since done a ton of work on it and the most efficient course of action is to copy the Part Numbers based on an old version of the table.

Comment: I believe the following will give you the desired results. But it based on a join: `UPDATE  parts2
 JOIN
        parts
SET     parts2.PartNumber=parts.PartNumber
WHERE   parts2.id=parts.id` ?

Comment: Yes, it did.  I will accept your answer since you got to it first in the comments.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following will give you the desired results. But it based on a join:

```
UPDATE parts2,
       parts 
   SET parts2.PartNumber=parts.PartNumber 
 WHERE parts2.id=parts.id;
```

It will do exactly what you want. And it is a most efficient way. I don't see any sence in trying to avoid `JOIN` here

Comment: Accepted for getting to it first in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by joining **parts** and **parts2** table .

```
UPDATE parts2 AS p2
INNER JOIN parts AS p1
 ON p1.id= p2.id
SET p2.PartNumber=p1.PartNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [UPDATE JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/) syntax

```
UPDATE parts2
    JOIN parts ON parts2.id=parts.id
SET parts2.PartNumber=parts.PartNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this.

```
UPDATE parts2 
SET parts2.PartNumber=parts.PartNumber from parts
WHERE parts2.id=parts.id;
```

you just needed to specify the table **parts** in the **SET** property.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE parts, parts2
SET p2.PartNumber=p1.PartNumber  
FROM parts p1, parts2 p2
WHERE p1.id = p2.id
```